# Is it possible to show a little of the next fragment on viewpager in Android?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager

I want to show a small part of (for example 30dp) the next (2nd) fragment on the current (1st) fragment. Similar to Windows Phone. So user can feel the existence of the draggable, changable  fragment/page easily.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Override `getPageWidth()` on your `PagerAdapter` and return a value from `0.0f` to `1.0f`, indicating what proportion of the `ViewPager` widget this page should take up. A value like `0.8f` should give you the effect that you are seeking.

Comment: I am using FragmentPagerAdapter and there is no getPageWidth() that I can Override :|

Comment: @frankish: Yes, there is, inherited from `PagerAdapter`: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/PagerAdapter.html#getPageWidth(int) If you are not seeing that method, make sure that you are on a current version of the Android Support JAR.

Comment: Sometimes a black vertical line appears at the right side of the current fragment. When I change orientation to horizontal and back to portrait again it changes location from for example 2nd fragment to 4th fragment. It also doesn't appear on landscape orientation. I looked into layout files but couldn't find anything about that. What can be the problem?

Comment: @frankish: I have no idea, in part because I do not completely understand your question. Consider opening a fresh StackOverflow question, posting code and screenshots, and explaining a bit more about what you are seeing and how you are getting those results.